# Adding a subview to a UINavigationBar disables interaction of bar buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, uinavigationbar, interaction

I have a UINavigationBar subclass that overrides awakeFromNib. I'm simply adding a UIView subview to the navigation bar. When I do, it displays correctly, but interaction of the default back button item is disabled.

Any help is appreciated.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, kDeviceWidth, 64)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self insertSubview:view atIndex:0];

[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting the view below the back bar item in the view hierarchy?

Comment: Your view is probably sitting on top of the back button and preventing it from receiving touches.

Comment: Solved: create a UINavigationController subclass and do [self.view insertSubview:view belowSubview:self.navigationBar];